# jQuery broken href

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've a jQuery Mobile app. The app pulls JSON data from the backend and presents it to the user.

From last 2 days i'm stuck with a weird issue. While presenting the data to the user, I'm trying to make use of `<a href="url"></a>` tag. It's a very simple line of code and I just don't understand what is the issue with something so simple.

### Code Snippet

```
$.each(obj, function(entryIndex, entry) {
            //some code
         html += '<a href="retrieveDetails.jsp?reference=' + entry.reference + '"><h3 class="term">' + entry['name'] + '</h3></a>';
         //some more code
      });
```

### Issue

When I try to click on the hyperlink, I see the following error in FireBug console.

```
j.data("page") is undefined
animationComplete()jquery....min.js (line 54)
error()
```

### What am I using?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

I will appreciate if someone can guide me.

Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information in order to give an answer. Do you redirect when clicking the anchor? What is going on in the new page?

Comment: NO,there's no redirection. When I click on the hyperlink, I See the following error in my FireBug Console Window.

.data("page") is undefined
animationComplete()jquery....min.js (line 54)
error()jquery....min.js (line 59)
[Break On This Error]  

...Scroll",S);H.data("page")._trigger("beforehide",null,{nextPage:j})}j.data("page"...

jquery....min.js (line 54)

Looking at the error, it appears that it has to do something with jQuery JavaScript lib which I imported.

Comment: Paste your **Full** code to a jsFiddle demo

Comment: We need to see the ENTIRE code of the click handler.  Obviously an error is occurring in the clickhandler, but you choose to only show us some code which has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't really help

Comment: What doesn't really help?  He's asking you to create a working demo at jsfiddle.net.  It will only help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here.

- You are using an old non stable version of JQM. Upgrade to the latest stable version.
- I suspect your page that your linking to does not contain a div with
  data-role="page". That is probably the reason why the error says j.data("page") is undefined. When JQM(jQuery mobile) grabs your other page it
  looks for a div with that data attribute. That is the portion it
  inserts into the original pages dom.

This is an example of the div JQM looks for when it inserts a new page into the dom.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```